# Sporadic extremly slow read speed on hard disk

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance, sata

For some time I have a sporadic issue with my hard disk, showing up in the form of extremely slow access time (~200 ms according to Windows) and read speed (~ 1 MB/sec). This holds even for sequential access, e.g. trying to copy a large file. However, write speed is absolutely normal (> 100 MB/sec) *when copying from another disk*. Rebooting often makes the issue go away until the next restart.

This is what it looks like in Windows when the issue occurs:
[image: This is what it looks like in Windows]

Sometimes I have the feeling that if I quickly access the drive after booting that the issue does not occur.

This is a secondary classical magnetic hard disk, Windows is install on an SSD, which does not have these issues at all.

What I already tried:

- Reinstalling Intel Storage drivers
- Using a different SATA Port on the mainboard
- Using a different hard disk

None of these helped - the other hard disk had the exact same issue. So I do not think it is a defect in the hard disk.

Some background info:

1. Windows 10
2. Mainboard is MSI Z170 Carbon
3. The issue occured with a
       Seagate Barracuda 2TB and with a Seagate Firecuda 2TB

Comment: check SMART data with CrystalDiskInfo, maybe you have drive issues

Comment: @magicandre1981 As I wrote above I tried with two different hard disks. CrystalDisk shows problems for none of the two.

Comment: still run it and look if you have CRC  issues. Here you could have a bad SATA cable.